# Why doesn't GeoGebra show the points of intersection between two ellipses when they are tangent?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, intersection-theory

I drew two ellipses in GeoGebra that have a common focus and my purpose is to show all cases of their relative geometries. I used the `Intersect(Object,Object)` function to automatically detect possible intersections but the function fails when I insert the data that yields to tangency condition (that I previoulsy computed with Matlab).
My GeoGebra project is at the following link: [relative_geometry_ellipses](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ecpbm7jz)
Can you take a look at the project and tell me if it is a bug of `Intersect(Object,Object)` or if I have to use a different function?
[image]

P.s. the function works well in case of two distinct intersections as shown here:
[image: relative_geometry_two_intersections]

Comment: I'm seeing two intersection points close together with 16.75 degrees. edit: nvm I see you went to four decimal places. Is that the exact value or an approximation?

Comment: Hi @DavidP, it is an approximation. The matlab results is: `16.749125863754580` (double precision).

Comment: If you type in the entire 16.749125863754580, it gives just one point.

Comment: Thank you @DavidP, problem solved!